# Cannot access notification through Android AccessibilityService

Tags: android, notifications, android-service, android-notifications, accessibilityservice

I am trying to access the notifications on my android phone using the AccessibilityService.

I tried making a service and calling it from the main activity. I've also added meta for the service. It's not working. I cannot see the triggering of the service.

I'm using Android L for testing. In accessibility settings I've added my app 'Notify' as on.

Thanks in advance.

**My main Activity**

```
package com.example.tony.notify;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS), 0);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyAccessibilityService.class);
        startService(i);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**This is my service class**

```
package com.example.tony.notify;

import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by tony on 9/7/15.
 */
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

    final String TAG = "Notification service";

    private String getEventType(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        switch (event.getEventType()) {
            case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED:
                return "TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED";
            case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED:
                return "TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED";
            case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED:
                return "TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED";
            case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_LONG_CLICKED:
                return "TYPE_VIEW_LONG_CLICKED";
            case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SELECTED:
                return "TYPE_VIEW_SELECTED";
            case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED:
                return "TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED";
            case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED:
                return "TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED";
        }
        return "default";
    }

    private String getEventText(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (CharSequence s : event.getText()) {
            sb.append(s);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

        Log.v(TAG, String.format(
                "onAccessibilityEvent: [type] %s [class] %s [package] %s [time] %s [text] %s",
                getEventType(event), event.getClassName(), event.getPackageName(),
                event.getEventTime(), getEventText(event)));

    }


    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {

        Log.v(TAG, "onInterrupt");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onServiceConnected();
        Log.v(TAG, "onServiceConnected");
        AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
        info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT;
        info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK;
        info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
        setServiceInfo(info);
    }
}
```

**My manifest for declaring service**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tony.notify" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <service android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice" />
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance. I've tried looking into some examples. I couldn't find errors.

Comment: What is in your `xml/accessibilityservice.xml`?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:notificationTimeout="100" />

This is my meta xml file

Comment: You don't have to start the accessibility service manually from your activity. System will start it for you when you enable it in accessibility settings. Some things like UiAutomator can break accessibility services so they have to be restarted from settings.

Comment: are you able to redirect user in accessibility service?

Comment: Do you get `onServiceConnected` by your service in the logcat output?

Comment: @IlyaPolenov I've also tried it without the explicit call from the activity. My logcat is not showing onServiceConnected.

Comment: @kiturk3 I didn't get what you were asking.

Comment: Everything seems ok. Try adding `android:enabled="true"` to your AndroidManifest.xml in `<service>` tag. Maybe it could help.

Comment: @IlyaPolenov Still not working. 
I have a logcat like this.


07-09 11:14:30.184  18150-18201/com.example.tony.notify I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-09 11:14:30.260  18150-18201/com.example.tony.notify D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0

Comment: That's just your main activity starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working on L though, it's not really working on api 16, I tested on one. Can anyone suggest an addition to make it work on api 14+

**Manifest File**

```
package com.example.tony.acctest;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.tony.acctest.MyAccessibilityService.Constants;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MA LOG";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(Constants.ACTION_CATCH_NOTIFICATION);
        registerReceiver(NotificationCatcherReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(NotificationCatcherReceiver);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver NotificationCatcherReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.v(TAG, intent.getStringExtra(Constants.EXTRA_PACKAGE));
            Log.v(TAG, intent.getStringExtra(Constants.EXTRA_MESSAGE));
        }
    };
}
```

**My service class**

```
package com.example.tony.acctest;

import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;

import java.util.List;


public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

    private final AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

        final int eventType = event.getEventType();
        if (eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED) {
            final String sourcePackageName = (String)event.getPackageName();
            Parcelable parcelable = event.getParcelableData();

            if (parcelable instanceof Notification) {
                List<CharSequence> messages = event.getText();
                if (messages.size() > 0) {
                    try {
                        final String notificationMsg = (String) messages.get(0);
                        Intent mIntent = new Intent(Constants.ACTION_CATCH_NOTIFICATION);
                        mIntent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_PACKAGE, sourcePackageName);
                        mIntent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_MESSAGE, notificationMsg);
                        MyAccessibilityService.this.getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(mIntent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected() {
        info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK;
        } else {
            info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
        }
        info.notificationTimeout = 100;
        this.setServiceInfo(info);
    }


    public static final class Constants {

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "extra_message";
    public static final String EXTRA_PACKAGE = "extra_package";
    public static final String ACTION_CATCH_NOTIFICATION = "com.example.tony.acctest.CATCH_NOTIFICATION";
    }

}
```

**This is my Main activity**
    package com.example.tony.acctest;

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.tony.acctest.MyAccessibilityService.Constants;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MA LOG";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(Constants.ACTION_CATCH_NOTIFICATION);
        registerReceiver(NotificationCatcherReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(NotificationCatcherReceiver);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver NotificationCatcherReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.v(TAG, intent.getStringExtra(Constants.EXTRA_PACKAGE));
            Log.v(TAG, intent.getStringExtra(Constants.EXTRA_MESSAGE));
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had done this when my widget got enabled:

```
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {

    super.onEnabled(context);
    String enabledListeners = Settings.Secure.getString(
            context.getContentResolver(), "enabled_notification_listeners");
    if (!enabledListeners.contains("Myalert")) {
        Intent i = new Intent(
                "android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
```

And in my manifest:

```
<service
        android:name="com.edgealert.NotificationMonitor"
        android:label="MyAlert"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.samsung.android.cocktail.action.COCKTAIL_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.samsung.android.cocktail.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/single_cocktail" />
    </receiver>
```