# Log cat unknown error on while running AccessibilityService in API 16 android

Tags: android, notifications, warnings, android-logcat, accessibilityservice

I'm having an unknown logcat warning and error message shown while I tried to run my code in API 16 of android. It's working in Android L. 
I'm trying to fetch notifications using the code.

Could anyone know this. Please help.

```
07-09 20:52:45.850  26369-26369/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
07-09 20:52:46.681  26369-26369/com.example.tony.acctest E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-09 20:52:47.362  26369-26369/com.example.tony.acctest I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
07-09 20:52:47.362  26369-26369/com.example.tony.acctest W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13334: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
07-09 20:52:47.362  26369-26369/com.example.tony.acctest D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
07-09 20:52:47.372  26369-26369/com.example.tony.acctest I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
07-09 20:52:47.372  26369-26369/com.example.tony.acctest W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 412: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
07-09 20:52:47.372  26369-26369/com.example.tony.acctest D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
07-09 20:52:47.372  26369-26369/com.example.tony.acctest I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
07-09 20:52:47.372  26369-26369/com.example.tony.acctest W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 434: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
07-09 20:52:47.372  26369-26369/com.example.tony.acctest D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
```

I'm not able to run the service, it's not working. As per my knowledge the code should work from API level 14.

To refer code, please take a look at my answer at [Cannot access notification through Android AccessibilityService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31308841/cannot-access-notification-through-android-accessibilityservice)

Answer (score 0):

The logcat error is still shwoing, but I found it. The code worked when I compiled it with API version 14.